# Finding planar curve $\beta(s)$ given curvature $k(s) = \frac{1}{s}$, $\beta(1) = (0, 0)$, $\beta'(1) = (1, 0)$

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, plane-curves

Find the curve $\beta(s) = (x(s),y(s))$ with $|\beta'(s)|= 1$ for all $s >0$ such that $\beta(1) = (0,0)$, $\beta'(1) = (1,0)$ , and curvature $k(s) =\frac{1}{s}$ for all $s >0$.

I am guessing some sort of integral is required since we are given 'initial' conditions, but I do not see how to begin.

Comment: It is not constant in our case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have a continuous function $k:(a,b)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ there exists always a planar curve $\beta:(a,b)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ parametrized by arc-lenght and such that $k_\beta(s)=k(s)$, where $k_\beta(s)$ is the curvature of such $\beta$.

In your case since $|\beta'(s)|=1$, then $k_\beta(s)=\theta'(s)$ where $\beta'(s)=T(s)=(cos\theta(s); sin\theta(s))$. In particular \begin{equation*}\theta(s)=\int k_\beta(s)ds
\end{equation*}is determined up to a constant (such constant will depend on the initial condition). In your case you have to integrate the function $\frac{1}{s}$ and once you have found $\theta(s)$ put it in the definition of $T(s)$ then integrate both coordinates to find $x(s), y(s)$ which are the components of the planar curve.

It's a useful exercise to do if your are approaching the first time to these topics.

**EDIT** Once you mandaged to solve the integral defining $\theta(s)$ you'll have an equation of the form $\theta(s)=f(s)+c$, where $f(s)$ is the function integrated and $c\in\mathbb{R}$. Put this (explicit) expression in $T(s)=\beta'(s)$ and use the hypothesis $\beta'(1)=(1,0)$, you'll find the constant $c$. The same will happen when you integrate $T(s)$ to find $x(s),y(s)$, you'll get another constant $\bar{c}$ and use the hypothesis $\beta(1)=(0,0)$

Comment: Thanks. For the integral, how do I find the constant? I am unsure of how to use the initial conditions. It is indeed my first time with these topics.

Comment: I have edited my answer. If you need more explanation let me know :)

Comment: Thank you. Last question: where did we use the condition $|\beta'(s)| = 1$?

Comment: At the beginning, to say that the curvature of beta is equal to the variation of the angle which define the tangent vector.

Comment: What would it be equal to if $|\beta'(s)| \ne 1$?

Comment: In that case you have to use the definition of curvature in terms of a determinant divided by the norm of a vector. But remember that you can always assume that your curve is parametrized by arc-length (at least in the regular case), the problem is that sometimes could be difficult to calculate it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Let's write everything down.
$$\left|\beta^{\prime}(s)\right|=1 \implies \left(x'(s)\right)^2+\left(y'(s)\right)^2=1$$
An arc length paramtrization of $\beta$ is going to be given by
$$\left(\int_1^s \cos(\theta(t))dt,\int_1^s \sin(\theta(t))dt \right)  $$
for some $\theta$. In the above equation we used the first initial condition.
The curvature is given by
$$\beta''(s)=\kappa(s) e_2$$
where $e_2$ is orthonormal to $\beta'$ so we have that
$$|\beta''(s)|^2=\frac{1}{s^2}$$
Thus we get
$$\sin^2(\theta(s))\theta'(s)^2+\cos^2(\theta(s))\theta'(s)^2=\frac{1}{s^2}$$
This implies
$\theta'(s)=\frac{1}{s}$. Thus we get $\theta(s)=\ln(s)$ by the initial condition for $\beta'$.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT1:

*Curve behavior*

The curve is natural or intrinsic. A rigid bent curved arc of this shape or can be moved anywhere in the plane merely by varying IC.

$$ \phi'=\frac{1}{s},\;\phi= \log\frac{s}{a}\;; \dfrac{s}{a}= e ^{\phi}$$

where $a$ is an arbitrary constant and $\phi$ is curve rotation with respect to x-axis.

$$ x=\int\cos \phi \;ds=\int\cos\log\frac{s}{a} ; y=\int\sin \phi \; ds=\int\sin \log\frac{s}{a} ds;$$

*Curve's  analytical parametrization*

$$\boxed{x= \frac{s}{2} [{\sin (\log (s))+\cos (\log (s));\;y=\sin (\log (s))-\cos (\log (s))}] } $$

Calculated by numerical integration. BC  $  (x=1,y=0) $

At start infinite curvature or Cusp occurs. Numerically,  $s=0 $ cusp is avoided, a small value given for x to avoid a singularity.

As $s\to \infty $ the curve becomes flatter.

I have not found a reference to this curve in *2dCurves, Lockwood, McTutor or Mathworld*

[image]